# Ubuntu repository MySQL5.5 vs Orace MySQL5.5

Tags: mysql

Ubuntu repo mysqld executable file size = 12 MB.
mysqld downloaded from Oracle website ~= 50 MB.

I compiled mysqld and the size again came out to be ~= 50MB

Mysqld 5.6 file size ~= 90MB

How is it that Ubuntu repo mysqld is so small in size.
What flags are used during compilation?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to:

1. Check if the Oracle mysqld was compiled with debugging information and try to strip it, e.g. run `strip mysqld` on resulting binary.  Debian/Ubuntu packages are automatically stripped.
2. Compare the `./configure` flags – there might be more engines or other features compiled-in in the Oracle build.  You can check the flags used to compiled Ubuntu package by downloading the source (`apt-get source mysql-5.5`) and checking the contents of `./debian/rules` inside unpacked source package.